# Magento 2 Set order attribute via order create api

Tags: magento2, attributes, orders, rest-api, magento2.3.1

I've created a couple of order attributes using the method described here (https://www.yereone.com/blog/magento-2-how-to-add-new-order-attribute/) in order to save some data that is passed into Magento 2 via our legacy application.

Is it possible to pass these values over when creating an order via the API? or is there a better way to achieve the same result? I'm using Magento 2.3 if that has any impact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First read this below articles:

- https://store.fooman.co.nz/blog/an-introduction-to-extension-attributes.html
- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html

If you want to add a field them you need to use [**extension_atttibutes**](https://store.fooman.co.nz/blog/an-introduction-to-extension-attributes.html)

***Extension attribute gives the facility to add a new field to existing API point.***

The fields which you have created using https://www.yereone.com/blog/magento-2-how-to-add-new-order-attribute/)  to be used as an extension attribute for  data `Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface`.

So, create `etc/extension_attributes.xml` at your module folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface">
        <attribute code="is_important" type="string" /> <!-- type defined as string -->
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

### Save field to order table

And as you have created the column to an existing order table, So save the create before plugin on `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface::save()`.

```
<?php

namespace Yereone\NewOrderAttribute\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;

class OrderSave
{

...

    public function beforeSave(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $subject,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $resultOrder
    ) {

    $extensionAttributes = $resultOrder->getExtensionAttributes();
        if (null !== $extensionAttributes) {
           $extensionAttributes->getIsImportant()->getValue();
           $resultOrder->setIsImportant( $extensionAttributes->getIsImportant()->getValue());   
    }
        return $resultOrder;
    }


 }
```

Comment: Seems like a sensible approach, my only comment would be if I save data as an extension attribute AND then save it to the order table fields I've added am I not just duplicating data? Is there any way to show extension attributes in the sales order grid?

Comment: @amith: thanks a lot for sharing the fooman link. More. It is more clear compared to the dev docs.

Comment: @Amit Bera Place order: [POST] /rest/V1/carts/mine/payment-information use this api and post but issue face Error: Call to a member function getValue() on null in /var/www/html/test/app/code/vendor/module/Plugin/OrderSave.php:20
Stack trace: